# When will MPI_Iprobe return true?

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing, hpc

I have an application where each processor needs to send data to particular number of processors and recv data from unknown number of processors with unknown data size all while doing local stuff. This is what I have in mind:

```
MPI_Isend(...)
// Do local computation
MPI_Wait(...)

int flag;
MPI_Status st;
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCES, tag, &flag, comm, &st);
While(flag) {
    MPI_Irecv(st.MPI_SOURCE,...);
    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCES, tag, &flag, comm, &st);
}
```

Am I guaranteed that `MPI_Iprobe` in this case will be able to find each and every one of the messages sent? I am suspicious that if current rank has less work to do it will reach `MPI_Iprobe` before other processors have had enough time to actually send the message in which case I will miss some messages. In that case, would use of `MPI_Barrier` after `MPI_Wait` solve the problem?

What other options do I have to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your problem, you could just use regular `MPI_PROBE`. That will block to wait for a message to actually arrive.

However, I'm not really sure why you need to use probe at all. It seems from your sample code that you'd be fine using a regular `MPI_RECV` with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`. `MPI_RECV` doesn't require a named source.

Comment: Problem is that number of individual messages, their sources, and all the message sizes are unknown. This means I cannot use `MPI_Probe` (I think) since I have no way of knowing how many times I should be calling it. IF I call it more than necessary, that process will get stuck forever! As for receiving, I'm using `MPI_Irec` to allow computation/communication overlap. What confuses me is I do not exactly know what makes `MPI_Iprobe` determine that a message has "arrived"